# Choose the right door for golds

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Choose the right door for golds.
Do it very carefully. 
If you choose the wrong door you will be dead.

[image]

Comment: Based on the comments on the accepted answer, it would appear this puzzle is ambiguous and thus not being logical-deduction, or there is no correct solution.

Comment: It has to be ambiguous; if correct means 'leads to gold', then we have no information and it could be any of them. If correct means true, then it can't be any of them.

Comment: If that is the case and it was the OP's true intention for "correct" to NOT mean the door telling the truth (with that being the only use of the word), then I'd say this is a poorly worded puzzle. https://xkcd.com/169/ +1 to everyone that answered that there's no correct solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 4th door on the second row. The one marked with "This door leads to death".

Explanation:

> There is only one door with the correct message and only one door that does not kill you.
>  This means that the door with the true message is the first one. "The correct door leads to golds".
>  This means that all the other doors a liars.   :)
>  This should be enough to conclude that the last door is the one you should choose because it states "This door leads to death" which is not true.
>  But let's go through all the other doors.
>  I cannot choose the second door (first row) because I would make 2 doors tell the truth.
>  3rd door: "The red and blue both lead to death."  This again points to the last door being the right one to choose because the statement is not true and we already decided the blue one is not good.
>  4th door: "one of the above leads to gold". This is false so the doors above lead to death.
>  5th door: "This door leads to gold". Again this is false so we eliminate this one.
>  So my assumption that the last door is the right one to choose still stands.

Sorry for using mostly coordinates and not colors. I'm slightly color blind and I had doubts about the color of some of the doors.

Comment: Doesn't "correct" mean "the true statement" here? If the white (1st) door is correct, and the red (6th) door leads to gold, then "the correct door leads to golds" is false, so this cannot be the solution.

Comment: @Kruga. No it doesn't. The correct message does not mean the right door. Imagine that instead of doors there are people. One tells the truth, the other ones are not. This does not mean that the truth teller guards the right exit.

Comment: So "The correct door leads to gold" really just means "The door you should choose leads to gold"? Then the use of "correct" on the white door and in the text is inconsistent and ambiguous, but perhaps that was the intention.

Comment: I thought you used coordinates because even the color of the doors might be a deception.

Comment: @GökhanKurt What colors? :D

Comment: @MOehm If that is the case then it's misleading us the wrong way.

Comment: Sorry, if "correct" can mean "the door to choose", then we no longer have a restriction on the number of doors with true statements on them.  In that case, any of the doors could lead to gold.  There is puzzle unless we assume that "correct" means "door has true statement on it".  By that interpretation, there is no solution.

Answer (score 9):

Unless I am missing something here:

> Choose the Red door.

Explanation:

> Obviously white door is correct because the OP gives that information in flavor text. This means all other doors are wrong(lying). Simple eliminating the options gives the red door as the answer.

Comment: The white door says the correct door leads to gold.  If it is the correct door, then it must lead to gold, not the red one.

Comment: @user3294068 The "correct" door leads to Gold. It doesn't explicitly say that the door which gives the right information is the "correct" door. And if we take the White door as correct door, then, more than 1 door will be giving right information, which is not possible according to the question.

Answer (score 7):

> Doomed to death.

> What the doors say:
>
> - White: THE CORRECT DOOR LEADS TO GOLDS (row: 1, column: 1)
> - Blue: YOU WILL CHOOSE THIS DOOR (row: 1, column: 2)
> - Green: THE RED AND BLUE DOORS BOTH LEAD TO DEATH (row: 2, column: 1)
> - Orange: ONE OF THE DOORS ABOVE LEADS TO GOLDS (row: 2, column: 2)
> - Yellow: THIS DOOR LEADS TO GOLDS (row: 2, column: 3)
> - Red: THIS DOOR LEADS TO DEATH (row: 2, column: 4)
>
> Let's consider the outcome for each door being correct, and the others lying. 
>  
>  White: Since the White door is the correct one, it must lead to the golds. However, that is contrary to the Green, Orange and Red doors, all of which must be lying, since if either the Red door or the Blue door leads to the golds, the White door can't, since we know that only one door leads to the golds, and if none of the doors above of the Orange door leads to golds, the White one can't lead to golds. Actually, if the White door is the correct one, then the Red door must lead to golds, something that contradicts what the White door says.
>  
>  Blue: If the Blue door is correct, we'll choose it. However, what it says is contrary to what the White, Orange and Red doors say, considering that they're all lying. We can't choose the correct door, since it will lead to death, but the Blue door is the correct door in this case, so that's a contradiction. Again, we can't choose any door above the Orange one, since it would lead  to death. Finally, since the Red door is lying, it must lead to the golds. 
>  
>  Green: If the Green door is correct, that means that the Blue and Red doors both lead to death. That's not the case here, since, if the Red door is lying, it must lead to golds. 
>  
>  Orange: If the Orange door is correct, then either the White door or the Blue door must hold the golds. The Blue door can't hold the golds, since, since it's lying, we won't choose it. So it must be the White door. Well, that still can't be the case, because the Red door must hold the golds, since it's lying about leading to death. 
>  
>  Yellow: Supposing that the Yellow door is telling us the truth, it must lead to golds. Of course, since the White door is lying, it can't lead us to golds. Additionally, since the Red door is lying, the Red door must lead to the golds too. 
>  
>  Red: With the Red door being correct, it must lead us to death. The Green door must be lying, so it's either the Blue or the Red door leading to golds. Since the Red door is leading to death, the Blue one must be leading to golds. However, the Blue door must be lying about us choosing it too, so we won't choose it. 
>  
>  That leaves us to the conclusion that we're doomed to death, since the door being referred to isn't one of the doors we can choose from. Additionally, "the other five" may refer to five of the six doors shown to us, but it doesn't say the sixth doesn't lead to death and the one is necessarily in there.

Comment: Nice explanation, but you start from a wrong assumption: "Since the White door is the correct one, it must lead to the golds". It does not state anywhere that the door that "tells" the truth is the door that leads to gold. The problem says "Exactly one door is correct" (my interpretation "the message on the door is true"). "Exactly one door leads to gold(s)". Id does not mean it's one and the same door in both cases.

Comment: @Marius You probably interpreted my explanation wrong, the assumption is because of what the white door says.

Comment: The instructions don't say the door with the true statement (the "correct" door) leads to gold. The instructions just say one door has a true statement and one door leads to gold. White has a true statement, red leads to gold.

Comment: @jaxad0127 Assuming that White is the correct door, it says that "THE CORRECT DOOR LEADS TO GOLDS" so if it tells the truth then it's also the one that leads to golds.

Comment: There are two meanings of correct here. One is the statement is true, the other is the door with gold. Part of the puzzle seems to be keeping those separate.

Comment: @jaxad0127 I'm keeping them separate too. If the door that says "The door that says the truth also leads to golds" tells the truth then it also leads to golds.

Comment: @jaxad0127 The problem is the puzzle has explicitly stated and used the word correct to mean the door that is not lieing, not the one that contains gold, in fact at no other point does the puzzle use correct to define holding gold. Also the meaning of the second interpretation is really weird, "the door that contains gold contains gold"

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's valid, but regardless of the text,

> I choose the red door

Because

> **Chose the right door**
> The red door is the only one to the right of every other doors.

Comment: This isn't [tag:lateral-thinking] unfortunately.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Indeed, it's not **lateral** thinking: it's **litteral** thinking...

Answer (score 3):

This is either a dumb puzzle with no solution, or worded incredibly poorly.  Down-voted.

This all relies on the White door.  Assuming the white door means the door with the true answer is the key:

You cannot choose white, because orange and red would be correct.
You cannot choose blue, because that would make orange, white, red, and blue correct.
You cannot choose green, because that would make red, green, and white correct.
You cannot choose orange, because that would make red and green correct.
You cannot choose yellow, because that would make red and yellow correct.
You cannot choose red, because that would make no doors correct.

If the white door is worded incredibly lazily **and contrary to the rest of the puzzle's definition of 'correct'**, and actually means that the door which doesn't kill you doesn't kill you, then you should choose:

> Red. It would be wrong, but since it would leave only one door that's 'correct' in that "the door which doesn't kill you doesn't kill you."

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean exactly with "The correct door leads to gold" ? If it means "The door telling the truth contains the golds", then :

> There is no solution !

Indeed:

> The red door has to be the answer (as hinted in the title), but it cannot be an answer.

because

> Green has to be lying otherwise red is also telling the truth (2 correct doors, impossible), so gold is behind red or blue, so if red tells the truth then orange also does (blue being the solution), so red lies, so red has the gold.

But:

> The red door can't be the answer, since all doors would have to be lying: obviously red is lying, so white is too, and it is obvious for the others, so I'd say there is no solution to your puzzle...

Answer (score 2):

(This answer supposes that "correct" means "telling the truth", not "the door with the golds behind it".)

> The gold is behind the red door, but you cannot choose it and be logically consistent. The only way to keep the set-up logically consistent is to choose the blue door and death.

Explanation:

> Suppose that the orange door is telling the truth. Then the golds are behind either the white door or the blue door (the doors on the top row). That would mean that every door on the bottom row has death behind it, and in particular the red door (last door on the bottom row) has death behind it. But then the red door is telling the truth, and as we have already supposed the orange door is telling the truth, there would then be two doors telling the truth, but we know that there is only one. So this does not work and we can conclude that the orange door is lying.
>
>  Thus neither of the doors on the top row leads to the golds. In particular, the blue door (second door on the top row) does not lead to the golds. Now consider the green door (first on the bottom row). If it is telling the truth, then the blue and red doors both lead to death. But then the red door (last on the bottom row) would also be telling the truth, and again we would have two truth-telling doors which is not allowed. So the green door must be lying. Thus the blue and red doors do not both lead to death. We already know the blue door leads to death, so the red door must lead to golds.
>
>  We now know that the red door leads to gold (and the others to death), and have established that the green and orange doors (first and second on the second row) are lying. We can also conclude that both the yellow and red doors (third and fourth on the second row are lying, because they both contradict the golds being behind the red door. We can conclude the white door (first on the top row) is lying because we know the golds are behind the red door, which we know is lying, so the correct door does not lead to the golds.
>
>  Thus we have established that every door is lying, apart from the blue door. To keep things logically consistent, we have to let this be the one door telling the truth, and the only way to do that is to choose it.
>
>  Goodbye world!

ETA supercat suggests that

> you could initially choose the blue door, to make its statement true, before changing your mind and going for the red door. Whether or not this would work will depend on how the universe interprets the blue door's statement (is it implicitly "you will choose this door at some point in your deliberation", or "you will choose this door as your final answer"?) and whether it can read your thoughts to pick up on that choice or is only able to register the action of opening and going through a door as one. So this strategy might fail, but since the alternative definitely leads to death, it certainly seems worth trying.

Comment: What if you initially "choose" the blue door, but then before you actually open it you "reconsider" and go through the red one instead?

Comment: @supercat I guess it depends how the universe defines "choose". It seems worth a go, though - got to be better than completely certain death!

Answer (score 2):

Answer :

> The red door.

Explanation :
Understanding what is given.

> We got 2 kinds of groups. The first is death and gold.
> The 2nd is correct and false. Each door has a statement that is either incorrect or correct.Taking the approach of true and false this is possible to solve.

Deducting which doors are the correct. Step 1.

> Either orange or green is correct. They're contradictory and in order to make a logical sense one of them must be correct to make consistent false statements.
>  I'm still looking for a way to deduct from those two doors.

Step 2 Concluding the door that leads to gold

> Now that we know that either the green based on the red door, which is false. >! It gives the opposite statement to "this door leads to death".
>  But we know there are two types of doors one to death and one to gold.
>  So if it's not to death, than it is to latter.

Answer (score 1):

I came to [the same conclusion as Neremanth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/54522/34791), but via a more concise/elegant argument.

Step 1: which door leads to golds

> If the red door leads to death, then it's correct, so all other doors must be incorrect. But then for the green door to be incorrect, the blue door must lead to golds, and for the orange door to be incorrect, the blue door must lead to death. This is a contradiction, so the red door must lead to golds.

Step 2: bad news

> Since the red door leads to golds, the white, green, orange, yellow, and red doors are all incorrect, which leaves only the blue door to be correct. This means that even though you know the red door is the one that leads to golds, you're going to be forced to choose the blue one instead somehow, and then you will be dead.

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

> The green door is correct and the gold door is orange.

Explanation:

> If any other door is correct, there are no possible candidates.
> Suppose orange door is correct and the blue door is incorrect: blue may be gold but you cannot choose blue. The incorrect green door eliminates the white door: either red or blue must be gold.
>
> By process of elimination, the green door must be correct. Then only one door can be gold. The others are eliminated. However it would violate the incorrect red door. So there can be no answers.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is wrong. I'd suggest reading the top answer which explains how to solve this puzzle.